# Vagrant access guest machine from host (windows)

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I installed a vagrant virtual machine in Windows, it's working fine, I am trying to connect to the guest machine from windows, but as soon as I uncomment some thing in Vagrantfile like :

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
```

OR

```
config.vm.network "public_network"
```

when reloading vagrant, I got this error :

```
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'poweroff' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.

If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
 it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
 VirtualBox GUI is open.

The primary issue for this error is that the provider you're using
is not properly configured. This is very rarely a Vagrant issue.
```

Comment: Have you had a look at VirtualBox gui?

Answer (score 1):

I know this does not make sense but I just open `VirtualBox` and with right-click goes to `Settings` of created vagrant machine image and diable `Audio` and it is working after save and run `vagrant up`

Answer (score 0):

I never encountered that error personally, having never used vagrant on  windows. This issue has been discussed [here.](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2157)